# SWIFT UI request

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, codable

Im trying to make a request on Swift UI in a data file, but nothing is happening on and I seem to not be getting back any data. Im not sure where the issue is, keep in mind I just started swiftUI 2days ago. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Data Im trying to retrieve.

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1119,
        "make": "Audi",
        "model": "100",
        "generation": "100 Avant (4A,C4)",
        "engine_modification": "2.8 V6 E (174 Hp) quattro Automatic",
        "year": 1991,
        "powertrain_architecture": "Internal Combustion engine",
        "body_type": "Station wagon (estate)",
        "number_of_seats": 5,
        "number_of_doors": 5,
        "urban_fuel_consumption": 13.5,
        "extra_urban_fuel_consumption": 8,
        "combined_fuel_consumption": 10,
        "fuel_type": "Petrol (Gasoline)",
        "acceleration": 9.5,
        "top_speed": 207,
        "power": 174,
        "torque": 250,
        "engine_location": "Front, Longitudinal",
        "engine_displacement": 2771,
        "number_of_cylinders": 6,
        "position_of_cylinders": "V-engine",
        "number_of_valves_per_cylinder": 2,
        "fuel_system": "Multi-point indirect injection",
        "engine_aspiration": "Naturally aspirated engine",
        "kerb_weight": 1550,
        "fuel_tank_capacity": 80,
        "drive_wheel": "All wheel drive (4x4)",
        "number_of_gears": 4,
        "front_brakes": "Ventilated discs",
        "rear_brakes": "Disc"
    },
    {
        "id": 1120,
        "make": "Audi",
        "model": "100",
        "generation": "100 Avant (4A,C4)",
        "engine_modification": "2.8 V6 E (174 Hp) quattro",
        "year": 1991,
        "powertrain_architecture": "Internal Combustion engine",
        "body_type": "Station wagon (estate)",
        "number_of_seats": 5,
        "number_of_doors": 5,
        "urban_fuel_consumption": 13.5,
        "extra_urban_fuel_consumption": 8,
        "combined_fuel_consumption": 10,
        "fuel_type": "Petrol (Gasoline)",
        "acceleration": null,
        "top_speed": null,
        "power": 174,
        "torque": 250,
        "engine_location": "Front, Longitudinal",
        "engine_displacement": 2771,
        "number_of_cylinders": 6,
        "position_of_cylinders": "V-engine",
        "number_of_valves_per_cylinder": 2,
        "fuel_system": "Multi-point indirect injection",
        "engine_aspiration": "Naturally aspirated engine",
        "kerb_weight": 1550,
        "fuel_tank_capacity": 80,
        "drive_wheel": "All wheel drive (4x4)",
        "number_of_gears": 5,
        "front_brakes": "Ventilated discs",
        "rear_brakes": "Disc"
    },
```

Code for request

```js
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct astonMartin: Decodable, Identifiable{
    let id: Int
    var make: String
    var model: String
    var generation: String
    var engine_modification: String
    var year: Int
    var powertrain_architecture: String 
    var body_type: String
    var number_of_seats: Int
    var number_of_doors: Int
    var urban_fuel_consumption: Int
    var extra_urban_fuel_consumption: Int
    var combined_fuel_consumption: Int
    var fuel_type: String
    var acceleration: Int
    var top_speed: Int
    var power: Int
    var torque: Int
    var engine_location: String
    var engine_displacement: Int
    var number_of_cylinders: Int
    var position_of_cylinders: String
    var number_of_valves_per_cylinder: Int
    var fuel_system: String
    var engine_aspiration: String
    var kerb_weight: Int
    var fuel_tank_capacity: Int
    var drive_wheel: String
    var number_of_gears: Int
    var front_brakes: String
    var rear_brakes: String
}

class secondaryCall: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cars: [astonMartin] = []

    func getCars() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "URL INSERTED HERE") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }

            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decodedCars = try JSONDecoder().decode([astonMartin].self, from: data)
                        self.cars = decodedCars
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

content view

```js
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isLinkActive = false
    @EnvironmentObject var allCars: secondaryCall
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Image("car")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                    .overlay(
                        Rectangle()
                            .opacity(0.6)
                            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                    )
               
                    NavigationLink(destination: HomeView()) {
                        Text("Click to view all cars")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(.orange)
                    .clipShape(Capsule()
                    )
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
            

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(secondaryCall())
    }
}
```

Home view:

```
//
//  HomeView.swift
//  project
//

//

import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var allCars: secondaryCall
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            Text("All cars for Aston Martin")
                .bold()
                .textCase(.uppercase)
                .font(.headline)
            ForEach(allCars.cars){car in
                HStack(alignment: .top){
                    Text("\(car.make)")
                        
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            allCars.getCars()
        }
    
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
            .environmentObject(secondaryCall())
    }
}
```

Project App

```js
//
//  projectApp.swift
//  project
//

//

import SwiftUI
@main 
struct projectApp: App {
    var allCars = secondaryCall()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SplashView()
                .environmentObject(allCars)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must have some clue what’s happening, is the data downloaded, is the decoding working etc etc. Where in the chain do you believe the issue is?

Comment: It's just some light-hearted humour (IDK if it comes across that way over the internet). If I could help, I would have, but I couldn't, so I didn't.

Comment: @Alexander, my bad :) my apologies!

Comment: @Leander That said, on a more serious note, your question would get more positive attention if you sort out the grammar and punctuation, give a more useful/descriptive title, slim down the code snippets where possible, etc.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, thanks @Alexander :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your data, I see that the reason you not getting data is that because you construct some variables in struct `astonMartin` with wrong type compare to the JSON you given.

Given you some example

- In Json: `"urban_fuel_consumption": 13.5,` which should be `Double` but in struct `astonMartin` you set is `Int`
- In Json: `"acceleration": null,` which should be `Double?` because it is nil here but in struct `astonMartin` you set is `Double`
- In Json: `"top_speed": null,` which should be `Int?` because it is nil here but in struct `astonMartin` you set is `Int`

And maybe more of that ...

You should recheck each type of variables in your struct

Code will change like follow

```swift
struct astonMartin: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var make: String
    var model: String
    var generation: String
    var engine_modification: String
    var year: Int
    var powertrain_architecture: String
    var body_type: String
    var number_of_seats: Int
    var number_of_doors: Int
    var urban_fuel_consumption: Double // was Int
    var extra_urban_fuel_consumption: Int
    var combined_fuel_consumption: Int
    var fuel_type: String
    var acceleration: Double? // was Int
    var top_speed: Int? // was Int
    var power: Int
    var torque: Int
    var engine_location: String
    var engine_displacement: Int
    var number_of_cylinders: Int
    var position_of_cylinders: String
    var number_of_valves_per_cylinder: Int
    var fuel_system: String
    var engine_aspiration: String
    var kerb_weight: Int
    var fuel_tank_capacity: Int
    var drive_wheel: String
    var number_of_gears: Int
    var front_brakes: String
    var rear_brakes: String
}
```

More over, when you parse json not right it prints error in debug mode because you currently catch error there. Make sure you notice that.

[image: Parsing error]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will fix the errors you have pointed out and take it from there :)